# firebase read data kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to kotlin. And only I teach him. If you can help me.
I have again questions about firebase.
I have such a structure:

```
{
  "BarcodeBase" : {
    "Pepsi" : {
      "Pepsi Black" : {
        "barcode" : "4820036487899",
        "namebar" : "Pepsi Black"
      },
      "Pepsi Chery" : {
        "barcode" : "4820036487789",
        "namebar" : "Pepsi Chery"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "4WZ8sYdLfNeNTDH7t0JZXKbNdmF2" : {
      "company" : "Pepsi",
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "id" : "4WZ8sYdLfNeNTDH7t0JZXKbNdmF2"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to output namebar and barcode.
I write to the database like this:

```
private fun addbarcode() {
    val name = etname.text.toString()
    val barcode = etNumber.text.toString()
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please enter name...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(barcode)) { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please enter barcode!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return }
    val dataMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    dataMap[CHILD_NAMEBARCODE] = name
    dataMap[CHILD_BARCODE] = barcode
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_BARCODE).child(USER.company).child(name)
        .updateChildren(dataMap).addOnCompleteListener { task2 ->
            if (task2.isSuccessful) Toast.makeText(Iconics.applicationContext, "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    return }
```

Which child do I need to use in other activities after (USER.company)?

Sorry for my bad english(

**--------------------UPDATE**

```
inline fun initBarcode(crossinline function: () -> Unit) {
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_BARCODE).child(USER.company).child(I do not know what can be used here)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener {
            BARCODE = it.getValue(BarcodeDBModel::class.java) ?: BarcodeDBModel()
            if (BARCODE.namebar.isEmpty()){ BARCODE.namebar = "Ошибка" }
            function()
        })
}
```

Here is my output code. But it does not work as I need. I need to change it so that it works. But I dont know how.

Comment: None of your code reads from the database yet. If you haven't done so yes, I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events), and the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: Check update please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the key of the child to read (like `Pepsi Black` or `Pepsi Cherry`) you can pass it to the child method:

```
REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_BARCODE).child(USER.company).child("Pepsi Black")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener {
        BARCODE = it.getValue(BarcodeDBModel::class.java) ?: BarcodeDBModel()
        if (BARCODE.namebar.isEmpty()){ BARCODE.namebar = "Ошибка" }
        function()
    })
```

If you don't know the key, you can read all children and then loop over them:

```
REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_BARCODE).child(USER.company)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener {
        for (snapshot in it.children) {
            BARCODE = snapshot.getValue(BarcodeDBModel::class.java) ?: BarcodeDBModel()
            if (BARCODE.namebar.isEmpty()){ BARCODE.namebar = "Ошибка" }
        }
        function()
    })
```

Comment: Hi. I used RecycleView.